# Split a string by backslash

Tags: python, string, split, backslash

I am trying to split a path to get the name of the file, the last part of the string, and I am dealing with a problem that I am not being able to solve:

My string: `te = 'C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Excel_Reports\1837.xlsx'`

I have done this:

```
>>> te.split('\\')
['C:', 'Users', 'Desktop', 'TEST', 'Excel_Reports\x01837.xlsx']

>>> te.split('\\')[-1]
'Excel_Reports\x01837.xlsx'
```

I do not know what is the problem with `\0` or `\number`....is it any special Python character??

Here is what I would like to get:

```
['C:', 'Users', 'Desktop', 'TEST', 'Excel_Reports', '1837.xlsx']
```

But I can't get exactly this.

PD: is not a valid solution something like file_name = te[-5:-1] because the name of the excel file can be different anytime, always numbers though.

**EDIT:** **Showing how I am getting `te`**

```
folder = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Load excel")

for f in os.listdir(folder):
    if f.endswith(".xlsx"):
        te= os.path.join(str(folder),str(f))
        #bla, bla, bla,......
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the answers and comments, they pointed me on the right direction.

However, I solved the issue just by replacing this line:

```
te= os.path.join(str(folder),str(f))
```

for this one:

```
te = os.path.join(folder,f)
```

And then, this works:

```
te.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

Gives the name (number) of the file without the extension `xlsx`

Comment: You should use raw strings `r'...'` when dealing with \ as the \ can escape certain characters, for example `\n` is "new-line".

Comment: You know forward slashes work ok in windows and sidesteps those issues.

Comment: thanks Ffisegydd...I do not know what you mean by "raw strings"...but I will investigate. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals is the docs which may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the literal for `te` a raw string

```
>>> te = r'C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Excel_Reports\1837.xlsx'
>>> import os
>>> te.split("\\") # can't use os.path.sep as my repl is on linux
['C:', 'Users', 'Desktop', 'TEST', 'Excel_Reports', '1837.xlsx']
```

This is due to the syntax for python literal strings. `\g`, `\n`, `\t` etc would also cause problems. The other slashes don't *need* to be escaped since the character following isn't a valid escape sequence - but it's confusing as hell. Better to use the raw string syntax

If you're getting `te` from some place other than a source file eg an ini file or a database (as you should), you wouldn't even see this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a *correct* path, then:

```
import os

# Note that we're using the **r** prefix to make it a raw string - backslashes don't escape  
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Excel_Reports\1837.xlsx'
print os.path.split(path)[1]
# 1837.xlsx
```

You could also then further split to just get the base of the filename, eg:

```
print os.path.splitext(os.path.split(path)[1])[0]
# 1837
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `str.split` at all, using only `os.path` functions:

```
te = r'C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Excel_Reports\1837.xlsx'
print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(te))[0]
```

If you know in an advance that you are parsing Windows path, it is best to use `npath` - windows flavour of `os.path` module, so your code does it's job even if run on Linux:

```
print ntpath.splitext(ntpath.basename(te))[0]
```