# How to get two ints from a string like "45/9"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this string "45/9"

I want to get everything before the slash to be in int1
and get everything after the slash to be in int2.

(Please note: the numbers could grow to triple or even quadruple digits eventually)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605076/split-a-string-by-backslash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to integer with decimal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094717/convert-a-string-to-integer-with-decimal-in-python)

Comment: Read about Python fundamentals and most common functions available. Your question can be easily solved using `split` function. This is why you're getting so many downvotes as you don't seem to have done your research before posting the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python split string into multiple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703512/python-split-string-into-multiple-string)

Answer (score 0):

Just use string split

```
s = "45/9"
# split
[int1, int2] = s.split("/")
# convert from string to int
int1 = int(int1)
int2 = int(int2)
```

Comment: No need to explicitly create the list. A tuple is created implicitly, ie `int1, int2 = s.split("/")`

Answer (score 0):

```py
number = "45/9"
number1 = int(number.split('/')[0])
number2 = int(number.split('/')[1])
```

Comment: No need to split twice, just use `map`: `n1, n2 = map(int, number.split('/'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "45/9"

int1 , int2 = list(map(int, s.split("/")))
```

done. string split function splits the string at '/' character and returns a list. map function maps integer to each element of the returned list and returns map object. then used list constructor to create list and int1, int2 variable takes 1st and 2nd value.

Comment: Why are you converting to `list`? there is no need to since the `map` object is unpacked